# Postman: More descriptive tv4 validation error message

Tags: json, node.js, api, postman, tv4

I'm using [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to validate the schema of json data returned from an api.

I have a test that runs through basic http validation, then ends with:

```
if (tv4.error){
    console.log("Validation failed: ", tv4.error);
}
```

The error I get back is difficult to fathom.

> Validation failed: 12:22:41.316
>     Object:{}
>   message:"Invalid type:
>   number (expected string)"
>   name:"ValidationError"
>   type:"Error"

But I need to know which field the validation failed on. How can I get this info? The [npm page for tv4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tv4) suggests that the error message should be more descriptive.

Comment: try printing the whole tv4 object if you can see anything related in that

Comment: No there's nothing really useful on tv4 itself.

Answer (score 6):

According to the documentation of tv4, you can print the path of the error location using `console.log(tv4.error.dataPath)`, I have no idea why this attribute is not logged in the console.

Documentation is [here](https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4/blob/master/README.md).
The relevant section in the documentation is:

> If validation returns false, then an explanation of why validation failed can be found in tv4.error.
>
> The error object will look something like:
>
> ```
> {
>     "code": 0,
>     "message": "Invalid type: string",
>     "dataPath": "/intKey",
>     "schemaPath": "/properties/intKey/type"
> }
> ```

Comment: The console did not log any dataPath by just logging the tv4 result: `var res = tv4.validateResult(data, schema); console.log("res",res);`. I had to do add .error.dataPath to actually see the content `console.log("path",res.error.dataPath);`